# Graphql standard response format in case of partial failure of batch mutation request

Tags: graphql

I have a graphql mutation API which accepts a list as an input.
As per my business implementation, there's a possibility that few of the data provided in list may fail. In such case my graphql should have a node for both success and failure.
For e.g consider a scenario of delete. User will send a list of 10 ids to delete. Business implementation evaluated that 2 of them cannot be deleted. In such case my entire batch should not be rejected. My graphql response should indicate that 8 ids has been successfully deleted and 2 encounter failure (with reason). should I use graphql standard errors node (`GraphQlErrors`) or create a seperate error/failure node inside data node

```
{
  "errors": [
     "message": "id not found",
     "extensions" : {
        "code": "xyz",
        "innerCode": "ABC",
        "innerMessage": "No data found",
        "classification": "OTHER",
        "id": "<uuid>"                          <-- custom field
     }
  ],
  "data": {
      deleteRecords: [
         {"id": "123"},
         {"id": "456"}
      ]
   }
  
}
```

vs

```
{ "errors": [],
  "data": {
      deleteRecords: {
      "data":[
         {"id": "123"},
         {"id": "456"}
      ],
      "errors": [
        "message": "id not found",
         "extensions" : {
            "code": "xyz",
            "innerCode": "ABC",
            "innerMessage": "No data found",
            "classification": "OTHER",
            "id": "<uuid>"                          <-- custom field
          }
       ]
     }
   }
  
}
```